# LFTP: certificate common name doesn't match requested host name

Tags: certificate, debian-jessie

Using `lftp` to upload files to a remote server from two computers on my network. Using the exact same code this works fine on one and doesn't work on the other.
Transcripts of a problem session and a successful session are shown below.
The error that I get is:

> Certificate verification: certificate common name doesn't match
>   requested host name

Googling this error finds a solution that seems to work for most people (using: `set ssl:verify-certificate no`). But as you can see in the transcripts below this doesn't work for the "problem computer".

Because both computers use the same DNS and router to get on the internet I can only assume that this may be caused by a different setting on the problem computer. Would love to get suggestions for stuff to check other than `lftp` settings.

**The problem computer**

Stock Debian system jessie 8.7: `3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lftp` version being used:

```
$ apt show lftp
Package: lftp
Version: 4.6.0-1+deb8u1
:
:
```

Failing session (hostname replaced by "example"):

```
$ lftp
lftp :~> debug
lftp :~> set
set dns:order "inet6 inet"
set file:charset UTF-8
set ftp:timezone ""
set net:max-retries 2
set net:timeout 30
set ssl:verify-certificate no
set xfer:log yes
set xfer:log-file /tmp/lftp.log
set xfer:max-log-size 1048576
set xfer:max-redirections 10
set xfer:verify-command /usr/share/lftp/verify-file
lftp :~> open example.nl
---- using user `ftp2@example.nl' and password from ~/.netrc
---- Resolving host address...
---- 2 addresses found: (▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮, ▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮)
lftp ftp2@example.nl@example.nl:~> dir
---- Connecting to example.nl (▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮) port 21
**** connect(control_sock): Network is unreachable
---- Closing control socket
---- Connecting to example.nl (▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮) port 21
<--- 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5b Server ready.
---> FEAT
<--- 211-Features:
<---  CCC
<---  PBSZ
<---  AUTH TLS
<---  MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;
<---  REST STREAM
<---  MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;
<---  LANG en-US.UTF-8*
<---  UTF8
<---  EPRT
<---  EPSV
<---  MDTM
<---  SSCN
<---  TVFS
<---  MFMT
<---  SIZE
<---  PROT
<--- 211 End
---> AUTH TLS
<--- 234 AUTH TLS successful
---> LANG
Certificate: OU=Domain Control Validated,OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard,CN=*.zxcs.nl
 Issued by: C=GB,ST=Greater Manchester,L=Salford,O=COMODO CA Limited,CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
WARNING: Certificate verification: Not trusted
WARNING: Certificate verification: certificate common name doesn't match requested host name ‘example.nl’
<--- 200 Using default language en_US.UTF-8
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
<--- 200 UTF8 set to on
---> OPTS MLST modify;perm;size;type;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;UNIX.owner;
<--- 200 OPTS MLST modify;perm;size;type;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;UNIX.owner;
---> USER ftp2@example.nl
<--- 331 Password required for ftp2@example.nl
---> PASS XXXX
<--- 230 User ftp2@example.nl logged in
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/" is the current directory
---> PBSZ 0
<--- 200 PBSZ 0 successful
---> PROT P
<--- 200 Protection set to Private
---> PASV
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode (▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮).
---- Connecting data socket to (▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮) port 35302
---- Data connection established
---> LIST
<--- 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
Certificate: OU=Domain Control Validated,OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard,CN=*.zxcs.nl
 Issued by: C=GB,ST=Greater Manchester,L=Salford,O=COMODO CA Limited,CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
WARNING: Certificate verification: Not trusted
WARNING: Certificate verification: certificate common name doesn't match requested host name ‘ example.nl’
<--- 425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted
---- Closing data socket
<--- 450 LIST: Operation not permitted
**** extra server response
ls: Fatal error: max-retries exceeded
lftp ftp2@example.nl@example.nl:/>
```

**The other computer**

Debian-based Raspbian jessie 8.0 : `4.4.38+ #938 Thu Dec 15 15:17:54 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux`
On this computer I have the exact same version of `lftp`:

```
$ apt show lftp
Package: lftp
Version: 4.6.0-1+deb8u1
:
:
```

But now the `lftp` session gives no problems:

```
$ lftp
lftp :~> debug
lftp :~> set
set dns:order "inet6 inet"
set file:charset UTF-8
set ftp:timezone ""
set net:max-retries 2
set net:timeout 30
set ssl:verify-certificate no
set xfer:log yes
set xfer:log-file /tmp/lftp.log
set xfer:max-log-size 1048576
set xfer:max-redirections 10
set xfer:verify-command /usr/share/lftp/verify-file
lftp :~> open example.nl
---- using user `ftp2@example.nl' and password from ~/.netrc
---- Resolving host address...
---- 2 addresses found: ▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮, ▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮
lftp ftp2@example.nl@example.nl:~> dir
---- Connecting to example.nl (▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮) port 21
**** connect(control_sock): Network is unreachable
---- Closing control socket
---- Connecting to example.nl (▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮) port 21
<--- 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5b Server ready.
---> FEAT
<--- 211-Features:
<---  CCC
<---  PBSZ
<---  AUTH TLS
<---  MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;
<---  REST STREAM
<---  MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;
<---  LANG en-US.UTF-8*
<---  UTF8
<---  EPRT
<---  EPSV
<---  MDTM
<---  SSCN
<---  TVFS
<---  MFMT
<---  SIZE
<---  PROT
<--- 211 End
---> AUTH TLS
<--- 234 AUTH TLS successful
---> LANG
Certificate: OU=Domain Control Validated,OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard,CN=*.zxcs.nl
 Issued by: C=GB,ST=Greater Manchester,L=Salford,O=COMODO CA Limited,CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
WARNING: Certificate verification: Not trusted
WARNING: Certificate verification: certificate common name doesn't match requested host name ‘example.nl’
<--- 200 Using default language en_US.UTF-8
---> OPTS UTF8 ON
<--- 200 UTF8 set to on
---> OPTS MLST modify;perm;size;type;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;UNIX.owner;
<--- 200 OPTS MLST modify;perm;size;type;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;UNIX.owner;
---> USER ftp2@example.nl
<--- 331 Password required for ftp2@example.nl
---> PASS XXXX
<--- 230 User ftp2@example.nl logged in
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/" is the current directory
---> PBSZ 0
<--- 200 PBSZ 0 successful
---> PROT P
<--- 200 Protection set to Private
---> PASV
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode (▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮).
---- Connecting data socket to (▮▮▮▮▮▮▮▮) port 35035
---- Data connection established
---> LIST
<--- 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
Certificate: OU=Domain Control Validated,OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard,CN=*.zxcs.nl
 Issued by: C=GB,ST=Greater Manchester,L=Salford,O=COMODO CA Limited,CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
WARNING: Certificate verification: Not trusted
WARNING: Certificate verification: certificate common name doesn't match requested host name ‘example.nl’
---- Got EOF on data connection
---- Closing data socket
drwxr-xr-x  11 ftp      ftp          4096 Feb 11 16:56 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 ftp      ftp          4096 Feb 11 16:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 ftp      ftp          4096 Dec 29 10:48 01.home
lftp ftp2@example.nl@example.nl:/>
```

Comment: FTP data transfers are _always_ specified using IP addresses, never DNS names.  Thus the certificate name checking against hostnames, for the data transfer connection, will never succeed.  Also, the relevant `lftp` setting that you want, I think, is `ssl:check-hostname no`, rather than `ssl:verify-certificate`.

Comment: "FTP data transfers are always specified using IP addresses, never DNS names"  This is new to me (do you have a reference for this?). I always `open` a connection to a FQDN not to an IP address. And also, it doesn't seem to explain why stuff IS working on the other computer. Re `ssl:check-hostname` : thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work. I've added the info to the question.

Comment: FTP uses _two_ TCP connections; one for the control channel (that's the one that's usually on port 21, and for which you are probably using a DNS name); the other is for data transfers (and the addresses/ports for these data transfer connections are negotiated as part of the protocol, using _only_ IP addresses).

Comment: Also, by using `ssl:check-hostname off`, you *have* changed the behavior that you originally reported: you are no longer seeing "certificate common name doesn't match requested host name".  So you have effectively changed your post -- which makes it more confusing for future readers just what problem(s) you are trying to solve.

Comment: You are right. That addition was totally off-topic. I've removed the info as it does not help solve my problem. So, two computers, one method. One fails, one succeeds. All bets still on.

Comment: Well, the use of `ssl:check-hostname off` addresses the titled issue.  But it sounds like the _real_ problem is that you have issues with data transfers; the "common name" check is a red-herring.  Is that correct?  If so, one potential cause of data transfer issues are firewalls/routers which inspect the FTP control channel to dynamically open ports for the data transfers; such network middleboxes often cannot work when the control channel becomes encrypted via TLS -- and thus will not open the necessary ports for the data transfer.

Comment: Your assistance is greatly appreciated. How would I test if the necessary ports are being opened or not? The firewall (both `ufw` and `iptables`) on the problem system is disabled.

Answer (score 11):

As the comments said, ssl:check-hostname will work. It can be set in lftp shell by

```
set ssl:check-hostname no
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar problem in Amazon Linux 2 below helped me.

Append the file "/etc/lftp.conf" and try connecting again.

`vi /etc/lftp.conf` and append as below.

validate it as below.

```
cat /etc/lftp.conf | grep hostname
set ssl:check-hostname no
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused by outdated SSL libraries.
Also, if it is a `ProFTPd` server, there is a hint to add `TLSOptions NoSessionReuseRequired` in its config.
Have you seen you ftp server's logs?